# Why does form.reset() not work from a reset handler?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener("reset", resetHandler, false);

function resetHandler (evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();
    document.forms[0].reset();  // this does nothing
}
```

In this example, `reset()` has no effect (tested in Firefox and Chrome).
The exact same thing works as expected for the "submit" event.
Why?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wcLLtkaL/

Comment: PS, I'm fully aware that the code in this example is not very useful by itself :)

Comment: This is bizarre, but do you need it? The javascript should execute before the reset happens, so unless you're doing anything async that requires a return it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @jesse-kernaghan: The original handler where I noticed the problem has additional abilities. Depending on the situation it may replace the values with "intelligent" defaults, or perform an actual reset. The solution was to move `preventDefault()` to the branch that does the custom resetting, but the question remained why that was even necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#resetting-a-form) says:

> When a form element form is reset, the user agent must fire a simple event named reset, that bubbles and is cancelable, at form, and then, if that event is not canceled, must invoke the reset algorithm of each resettable element whose form owner is form.
>
> When the reset algorithm is invoked by the `reset()` method, the reset event fired by the reset algorithm must not be trusted.

This is exactly what happens when button is pressed or `f.reset()` is called: An event is created. But since you cancel the event (`evt.preventDefault()`), the "reset algorithm of each resettable element" step is not performed.

This looks like it should go into an infinite loop (`reset()` methods triggers `reset` event, which calls `reset()` method with triggers...), however, [there seem to be additional steps taken to prevent that](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-reset).

You can easily verify that `f.reset()` triggers the `reset` event by moving the call outside the method:

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener("reset", resetHandler, false);

function resetHandler (evt)
{
    console.log('reset');
    evt.preventDefault();
}

document.forms[0].reset();
```

This will log `"reset"`, indicating that all `.reset()` does is triggering the event. And only if the event is not canceled the form is actually reset.

---

But why does `submit()` behave differently?

[Calling the `submit()` method](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#concept-form-submit) does not actually trigger a `submit` event and therefore the action to be taken is not canceled.

Comment: Much better detail than my answer, nice job

Comment: A very good and detailed explanation, thanks. What an odd thing to specify, though. I assume this had more to do with staying backward compatible with existing browser behavior than with reason or design.

Comment: @Zilk: Probably. Of course I may also interpret the spec incorrectly, so I encourage you to read it as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The "evt.preventDefault();" is preventing the default action of "reset". [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcLLtkaL/3/) with "evt.preventDefault();" commented out, showing it working.

```
var f = document.forms[0];

f.addEventListener("reset", resetHandler, false);
f.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler, false);

function resetHandler (evt)
{
    //evt.preventDefault();
    f.reset();  // this does nothing
}

function submitHandler (evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();
    f.submit();  // this works fine
}
```